# Can I get the perl debugger to automatically display the lines around the current one?

Tags: perl, debugging

I want to quickly step through my script in the debugger, but be able to **see the lines around the one being executed**.

n = next

v = view surrounding code

i.e. instead of pressing n, v, n, v, n, v, n, v. I just want to press n, n, n, n, n, and have it display 10 (or 20, or 30) lines of context automatically.

Is that possible? I know there's the post-prompt commands, but they are for perl commands, not debugger commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this post-prompt command `> @DB::typeahead=('v')`. Then the type ahead buffer will always get the 'v' command after each prompt. It is then executed automagically.

Comment: Thanks! I've since discovered that {{v does the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Trace mode might do that ("t" will toggle that). Check the [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html). Also check into [Frame Listing Output Examples](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Frame-Listing-Output-Examples).